# Overlaps html objects tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First let me explain the proble a little. I have a flash player (JWPlayer) and it shows pre-rolls ads that I need to mute. I've tried it through the API of JWPlayer but didn't work. Somehow the ads run on top of the player and no matter what I do I can't mute them. How can I a do the same to the ads? I mean, how can I put some html element or any other on top of the ad but still show it, only put it on a container that not allow the sound to hear. This is the page where I am doing this http://latinongroup.com/test/test_player_optimatic.html and the html code.

```html
<div id="player1">
    <div id="botr_Uk4i6oUf_9elyllvm_div_wrapper" style="position: relative; display: block; width: 302px; height: 252px;">
        <a id="beforeswfanchor0" href="#botr_Uk4i6oUf_9elyllvm_div" tabindex="0" title="Flash start" style="border:0;clip:rect(0 0 0 0);display:block;height:1px;margin:-1px;outline:none;overflow:hidden;padding:0;position:absolute;width:1px;" data-related-swf="botr_Uk4i6oUf_9elyllvm_div"></a>
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://assets-jpcust.jwpsrv.com/player/6/6124956/jwplayer.flash.swf" width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#000000" id="botr_Uk4i6oUf_9elyllvm_div" name="botr_Uk4i6oUf_9elyllvm_div" class="jwswf swfPrev-beforeswfanchor0 swfNext-afterswfanchor0" tabindex="0">
            <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">
            <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
            <param name="seamlesstabbing" value="true">
            <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
        </object>
        <a id="afterswfanchor0" href="#botr_Uk4i6oUf_9elyllvm_div" tabindex="0" title="Flash end" style="border:0;clip:rect(0 0 0 0);display:block;height:1px;margin:-1px;outline:none;overflow:hidden;padding:0;position:absolute;width:1px;" data-related-swf="botr_Uk4i6oUf_9elyllvm_div"></a>
        <div id="botr_Uk4i6oUf_9elyllvm_div_aspect" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div id="botr_Uk4i6oUf_9elyllvm_div_ping" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 10;"></div>
        <div id="botr_Uk4i6oUf_9elyllvm_div_vast" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 11; visibility: hidden;"></div>
        <div id="botr_Uk4i6oUf_9elyllvm_div_jwpsrv" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 12;">
            <div class="afs_ads" style="width: 1px; height: 1px; position: absolute; background: transparent;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to put the object into a sore of container in order to mute the sound. If any one have an idea please help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Do people still use flash? Sure fire way of alienating a large portion of the internet!

Answer (score 0):

Try `wmode="transparent"` for object as an attribute or as a param.

> transparent - The SWF content is layered together with other HTML elements on the page. https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html

Comment: Thanks, I tried it already and nothing still get to hear the ad's sound. I've noticed that every time an ad is displayed an iframe is added yo the page.